# Make a class that can be drawn to a Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

i am trying to make some kind of reflex like game for android, which draws circles in random places and the user must tap those circles as fast as possible. i am trying to make and addcircle(int amount) method, but for that i would like to redraw the same class, as it is the idea that the circles expand and then contract. so something like canvas.draw(MyCircleClass) would work. is it possible to create such a class that can be drawn to a canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a class that can be drawn to a `Canvas`, like `Rect`, `Bitmap` etc. Then to draw it on a `Canvas` you would call `canvas.drawRect(myRectWrapper.getRect())`.

The other way would be to wrap the `Canvas` itself. Then you can pass anything you like to it as long as you provide a method to transform your class into something, the `Canvas` can draw. It would look like `myCanvasWrapper.draw(myClass)`. Inside the `draw(myClass)`, your canvas wrapper would call `canvas.drawX(transformToX(myClass))`

The bottom line is that at some point you will need to call a`drawX()` method the original `Canvas`, providing one of the types it can handle.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a method in your class `void drawToCanvas(Canvas canvas)`?